# How can I find who is retaining an object?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, instruments

I've been having trouble with UITableView sending a message to dealloced delegate.
When dealloc in UIViewController which owns the tableView is called, tableView is still alive and the tableView is sending a message to its delegate. This crash is resolved by setting delegate = nil when the owner of the tableView releases the tableview in dealloc. I believe this is not necessary if memory management is done correctly.

I would like to know the way to figure out who is retaining the tableView.

Is there any way I can figure that out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your project with Instruments (menu *Product->Profile* in Xcode) and select *Leaks*. It will record for every object where has been created, retained, released, autoreleased, deallocated. You can even search for a memory address there. So all you need to do is a way to get the memory address of your object, e.g. you could print it to console. Most people don't know that but you can view the console from within instruments:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `tableView` is continuing to process after its delegate has been cleaned up; remember that delegates are assigned to `weak` reference properties, so are not retained by the `UITableView`. If you are collapsing the `ViewController` while the `UITableView` is still loading elements, you're going to see this crash. It is best to assign `.delegate = nil` in your dealloc if the class that's being deallocated was the delegate.

Comment: "remember that delegates are assigned to weak reference properties" - delegate for UITableView is set as @property(nonatomic, assign) id< UITableViewDelegate > delegate, that's why tableView still can send a message to an object that has been dealloced.

Comment: That's correct - `UITableView` was created pre-ARC, so you can consider `assign` == `weak` and `retain` == `strong`. After your `UITableViewDelegate` is deallocated, `UITableView` is no longer able to send messages to the object because the object doesn't exist. It can, however, attempt to send messages to the object at the memory address previously occupied by your `UITableViewDelegate`; this will most often result in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 2):

> This crash is resolved by setting delegate = nil when the owner of the tableView releases the tableview in dealloc. I believe this is not necessary if memory management is done correctly.

That is often true today, because delegates are often declared `weak`, which means that they are automatically set to `nil` when the underlying object is deallocated. But `UITableView` is older than that. It comes from pre-ARC days and its delegate is declared:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate
```

So if the delegate is deallocated, `UITableView` will point to unallocated memory.

This kind of crash usually means that you're trying to update your tableview when it isn't onscreen. The most common cause of that in my experience is observing notifications when you shouldn't be. You want to make sure that you observe notifications in `viewWillAppear:` and remove all observations during `viewDidDisappear:`. Similarly you shouldn't be observing KVO when you're offscreen (but I more often find this kind of crash indicates an `NSNotification`).

You should also make sure that no objects other than the delegate directly access the tableview. No one should be calling `reloadData` or the like from outside the view/delegate relationship. No one should be accessing the delegate's IBOutlet properties. Those kinds of things lead to these kinds of crashes. No one outside the delegate should ever have a reference to the table view.

And of course make sure that you're not updating the table view on a background thread. That probably isn't the case here; it tends to lead to other kinds of crashes. But it's one other possibility.